# Unable to connect to remote MQ

Tags: ibm-mq

I am trying to connect to remote IBM MQ server. But i receive the error Cannot load the library mqjbnd.dll. I am not sure why bindings mode is getting used. A snippet of code used is pasted below. After reading the replies at various including stack overflow found out that client mode should be used for my scenario. But i am unable to configure the client mode. Any help on this will be greatly appreciated

```
// Create a connection to the QueueManager
  System.out.println("Connecting to queue manager: " + qManager);
  MQQueueManager qMgr = new MQQueueManager(qManager);

  // Set up the options on the queue we wish to open
  int openOptions = MQConstants.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF | MQConstants.MQOO_OUTPUT;

  // Now specify the queue that we wish to open and the open options
  System.out.println("Accessing queue: " + qName);
  MQQueue queue = qMgr.accessQueue(qName, openOptions);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using client mode , series of properties will need to be set as you are connecting using TCP/IP . This for example will include , host , port and details that are needed for the program to connect to a QM over the network. An indicative example is here.

```
Hashtable<String, Object> mqKeyValueProps = new Hashtable<String, Object>();
mqKeyValueProps.put(CMQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, hostName);
mqKeyValueProps.put(CMQC.PORT_PROPERTY, new Integer(portNumber));
mqKeyValueProps.put(CMQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, channelName);
mqKeyValueProps.put(CMQC.USER_ID_PROPERTY, userID);
mqKeyValueProps.put(CMQC.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, password);
try
{

    MQQueueManager qMgr = new MQQueueManager(qManager,mqKeyValueProps);

    int openOptions = MQConstants.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF | MQConstants.MQOO_OUTPUT;

  // Now specify the queue that we wish to open and the open options
    System.out.println("Accessing queue: " + qName);
    MQQueue queue = qMgr.accessQueue(qName, openOptions);
}
catch (com.ibm.mq.MQException mqex)
{
   System.out.println("MQException cc=" +mqex.completionCode + " : rc=" + mqex.reasonCode);
}
```